# asp.net Identity tables not get created

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm using the web api 2.2 template with OWIN and Identity framework. I've purposefully set my DeafultConnection to a bad IP address yet I get no errors when stepping through and getting a bearer token and creating claims.

I can kill the w3wp.exe, start it up again and my token is still valid. So where is it getting persisted?

I am manually validating a test user in my **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()** method

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tables get created when you first register a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can kill the w3wp.exe, start it up again and my token is still valid. So where is it getting persisted?

OAuth tokens are not persisted at all, in the default Owin OAuth2 implementation they are stateless by design. Each token contains the claims issued for the user encrypted by the server so that only it can decrypt and validate it.

If you validate your user without hitting your database (I assume this is what you mean when you say *manually* inside your `GrantResourceOwnerCredential` method) then of course you `DbContext` never get instantiated.

Comment: Thank you this makes perfect sense! So if I do my own user validation, where else does the IdentityDbContext get used? Seems like a waste to adding the Identity framework.

Comment: If you do not use ASP.NET Identity for managing your users (user creation, validation, etc.) then you may remove it. It is used by the default template, but if you completely replaced the default user management then you will not need it.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I removed all the Identity stuff and it's working great.